# Getting the database column name from the property of a grails domain

Tags: hibernate, grails

I'm mapping a bunch of legacy tables with my domain objects. Is there a way to find the database column name of a property in a Domain class (or vice versa)? For example:

```
class Person {

String firstName
.
.
.
}
```

is there a way to use firstName to get back the string "FIRST_NAME" or "first_name"? I've tried to use

```
GrailsDomainBinder.getMapping(Person).columns
```

but that only gives me the id column for some reason. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a mapping defined in your class?  `GrailsDomainBinder.getMapping(Person)` returns null if you don't have a custom mapping defined.  If you're not using a custom mapping than you know what the table name is based on the class name.

Comment: Yes there is a mapping defined. I screwed up in the title the first time...I'm actually looking for the column name from the property that it is mapped to. The point is that I'm given the actual column names and their values from a different part of the program and I need to map them to the right domain object to persist them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, I think this is what you're looking for.  Given the following domain

```
class Company {    
  String name
  String logoUrl

  static mapping = {
    table 'people'
    name column: 'my_name'
    logoUrl column:  'lo_go_url'
  }
}
```

You can retrieve the domain data with the following command:

```
def result = GrailsDomainBinder.getMapping(Company).columns
println result['logoUrl'].column //prints 'lo_go_url'
```

You could also print out all the column names with the following closure:

```
result.each{ key, val -> // The key is the attribute name in the class (i.e. name, logoUrl)
  PropertyConfig prop = val // This is not needed, but I wanted to show the type being used. You could just call val.column below.
  println prop.column // This would print out 'my_name', 'lo_go_url'
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Just tested here - not works when there's no custom column mapping.

Answer (score 8):

I just tossed this code together, so please don't beat me up on style. :-)

Try dropping it into a test action method in your `PersonController` and add my import statements and `sessionFactory` as shown below:

```
import org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.DefaultGrailsDomainClass

class PersonController {

    // This should get injected by Grails automatically
    def sessionFactory

    ....
    def myTestAction() {
        def domainClazz = grailsApplication.getClassForName("com.test.Person")

        def clazzMetadata = sessionFactory.getClassMetadata(domainClazz)
        def AbstractEntityPersister abstractEntityPersister = (AbstractEntityPersister) clazzMetadata
        def grailsDomainClazz = new DefaultGrailsDomainClass(domainClazz)

        def grailsDomainClazzProperties = grailsDomainClazz.getProperties()

        grailsDomainClazzProperties.each() {
            println "Property Name: ${it.name}"
            abstractEntityPersister.getPropertyColumnNames(it.name).each() {
                println "DB Column: ${it}"
            }
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: Although Michaels solution does work when columns are explicitly mapped, it breaks down for any column that is using the default mapping pattern.  This solution (in my limited testing grails 1.3.6) appears to work for both cases.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to get it in a bit hackish way :

```
 def dbColumnNames = sessionFactory.getClassMetadata(clazz).propertyMapping.getColumnNames(fieldName)
```

this returns an array of string in which the first element should be the DB column name of the field.

works under with Grails 2.3.6

Comment: verified on Grails 2.5.3

Comment: getClassMetadata() is deprecated, any alternatives?