# Get the database column name of a collection property of a Grails Domain

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I am trying to obtain the database column names for collection properties on my Grails domain classes.  I have a class like this

```
class Foo {
    static hasMany = [bars : Integer]
}
```

I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12289778/853054) and tried to implement the solutions.  It works for non-collection fields, but if I try it on `bars`, I get "`id`" as the column name instead of "`bars_integer`" which is what I need in this case.

Is there a way to get the column name easily with GORM/Hibernate?

## Edit

When running `grails schema-export` on this code, It produces the following:

```
create table foo (id bigint generated by default as identity, version bigint not null, primary key (id));
create table foo_bars (foo_id bigint, bars_integer integer);
```

Comment: Check in your database to see if a table called `foo_bars` exists.  If so, that's what it's under.  Columns should be `id`, `foo_id`, and `bars`

Comment: See my edits up above

Comment: Try using the [column](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Database%20Mapping/column.html) mapping property to point bars to the correct column.

Comment: The domain and database tables already exist.  I'm wanting to dynamically get the column name so that I can run a SQL query (what I need to do, I can't with HQL).