# How do I get a column name from Grails domain field name?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

My grails version is `3.3.6`. How do I get database column from a domain field name?

For example, here is my domain class:

```
class Domain {
    String myColumnName
}
```

I wish I could get the column name from such a method like this:

```
getColumnNameFromField('myColumnName') // will return 'my_column_name'
```

I use hibernate `5.2.17`, and `sessionFactory.getClassMetadata()` has been deprecated since hibernate 5.2: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/SessionFactory.html#getClassMetadata-java.lang.Class-

Any ideas ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting the database column name from the property of a grails domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12288650/getting-the-database-column-name-from-the-property-of-a-grails-domain)

Comment: No, that answer is a little outmoded. `sessionFactory.getClassMetadata` is deprecated.

Comment: Look at the other answer, `GrailsDomainBinder.getMapping(Domain).columns['myColumnName'].column`

Comment: Thanks. But it's only working if `column` set in domain class. So it's just a config from domain class, not mapping from database column.

Comment: You can still use `getClassMetadata` but the docs here https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/ say to 'Use the descriptors from EntityManagerFactory.getMetamodel() instead'

Comment: @MikeW I've got it, but I don't know how to use EntityManagerFactory.getMetamodel() to get column name.